# How do I step into C# Form()

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to debug the infamous UserPreferenceChanged hang problem, and I'd like to be able to step into the Form() constructor so I can set a break point where the system is checking if Synchronization is needed.

Unfortunately I'm unable to do that. Everytime I attempt to step into the code it simply steps over. I've gone through all the settings I can find mentioned on the web, but to no avail.

So the question is, how do I step into .NET Framework code?

Comment: Did the settings you've gone through include the ones in [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc667410.aspx)?

Comment: Also, if you haven't already, you may want to uncheck 'Enable Just My Code' in the main list in Options | Debugging.